# java сетевой фильтр

Tags: java

Необходимо написать приложение, которое блокировало бы доступ к определенным сайтам. С чего начать и куда копать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если коротко - нет, вы не можете написать полноценный брандмауэр на Java. Java не предоставляет настолько низкоуровневых API для работы с сетью. Вы могли бы написать модули работающие с сетью на Си и обращаться к ним через JNI, но зачем вам тогда тут Java?

Но у вас есть вариант написать на Java локальный прокси, фильтрующий доступ к сайтам. При этом браузер должен будет использовать этот прокси. А доступ по HTTP мимо прокси может быть закрыт средствами ОС/брандмауэра/маршрутизатора.